# Chart.JS: How can I only display data labels when the bar width is big enough for the text?

Tags: javascript, label, chart.js

I am using [Chart.JS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) with the [Chart.JS datalabel plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/). Is it possible to only show the data labels when the bar width is big enough for the text?

I have the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/f5p3twcg/2/

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    type: 'bar',
    options: {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                color: '#000000',
                display: true,
                formatter: function(value, ctx) {
                    return value + "kWh";
                }
            }
        }
    },
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Red1", "Blue1", "Yellow1", "Green1", "Purple1", "Orange1", "Red2", "Blue2", "Yellow2", "Green2", "Purple2", "Orange2", "Red3", "Blue3", "Yellow3", "Green3", "Purple3", "Orange3", "Red4", "Blue4", "Yellow4", "Green4", "Purple4", "Orange4"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

I know, this example doesn't make any sense, but you can see the issue.

If there is a lot of data, the data labels overflow the bar width like this:

[image]

Is there an option to tell Chart.JS to only show these labels when the text fits into the bar? (Otherwise just show the tooltips).

Comment: I know that this behaviour is standard for ZoomCharts (zoomcharts.com) (as I'm part of the team behind it) ;)

Comment: Good to know, but that doesn't help me... I do not want to switch the charting library again because its already used in several projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the graph isn't changing size dynamically you could obtain the width of a bar after creating the chart instance with

```
var width = myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0]._model.width;
```

and rewrite your formatter to check if the text width does not exceed bar's width

```
formatter: function (value, ctx) {
    function getTextWidth(text, font) {
        // re-use canvas object for better performance
        var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.font = font;
        var metrics = context.measureText(text);
        return metrics.width;
    }
    return getTextWidth(value + "kWh") > width ? "" : value + "kWh";
}
```

Please take a note of the fact that i ignored the font in the example before so you would have to extract it manually if any changes were made.

You could perhaps even write a plugin that would write into the `var width` variable before the render

```
plugins: [
    ChartDataLabels,
    {
        beforeRender: (myChart) => { width = myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[1]._model.width;}
    }
],
```

Comment: Hi, no, the chart is only printed once or updated completely (which means that its printed again). I will try your solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as expected after I did some smaller adjustments (See my answer here).

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [Krzysztof Krzeszewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10429793/krzysztof-krzeszewski) works. However, I had to slightly adjust it and add some checks for `'undefined'` in my case:

```
if (typeof chart !== 'undefined') {
    let datasetData = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);

    if (datasetData !== 'undefined') {
        if (datasetData.data.length > 0) {
            barWidth = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0]._model.width;
        }
    }
}
```